# ALAsset assetForURL causes important allocations never released

Tags: ios, memory-management, swift, memory-leaks

I use carousel to display local pictures in my app.

Every time I reload the view, I can see on "Instrument" with the "Allocation" tool that my app allocates memory for images, but never released it.

[image]

Below you can see the code:

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel!, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, var reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView!
{
    if view != nil
    {
        for subview in view.subviews
        {
            if let imageView = subview as? UIImageView
            {
                imageView.image = nil
            }

            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    let newView = UIView(frame: aFrame)

    self._getImageFromLocalWithPath(aPath, completion : { image in

            if image != nil
            {
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

                 newView.addSubview(imageView)
            }

        }
    )

    return newView
}

private func _getImageFromLocalWithPath(imagePath : String?, completion : UIImage? -> Void)
{
    autoreleasepool
    {
        ALAssetsLibrary.defaultAssetLibrary().assetForURL(NSURL(string : imagePath!), resultBlock: { asset in

                weak var wasset = asset

                if wasset != nil
                {
                    let image = UIImage(CGImage : wasset?.defaultRepresentation().fullScreenImage().takeUnretainedValue()) // This is the incriminated line!

                    completion(image)
                }
            },
            failureBlock: { error in

                completion(nil)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I've already found topics about this problem, but I've still my problem:

- [Cause of big memory allocation (memory leak?) when reading UIImage from camera roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400294/cause-of-big-memory-allocation-memory-leak-when-reading-uiimage-from-camera-r)
- [imageWithCGImage: GCD memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540713/imagewithcgimage-gcd-memory-issue) (About the solution proposed on this topic, I don't know if it's a really good idea to manually retain/release when using ARC in the project)

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem? Thank you